# Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: field "title" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a beginner in using Firestore and I'm facing this issue when trying to retrieve fields from the news collection.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class hom extends StatefulWidget {
  const hom({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<hom> createState() => _hom();
}

class _hom extends State<hom> {
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data = [];
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data2 = [];
  getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('news').get();
    data.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);

    setState(() {});
  }

  getData2() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("news").get();
    data2.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    getData2();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
              return Container(
                height: 136,
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFFE0E0E0)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          /*get field title*/ "${data[i]['title']}",
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        /*get field desc*/ Text("${data[i]['desc']}",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
                        const SizedBox(height: 8),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icons.bookmark_border_rounded,
                            Icons.share,
                            Icons.more_vert
                          ].map((e) {
                            return InkWell(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                child: Icon(e, size: 16),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                    Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              /*get field pic*/ image:
                                  NetworkImage("${data[i]['pic']}"),
                            ))),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is an image of the data in Firestore:

[image: firestore data]

I've checked the connection multiple times, there's no issue, and the fields are written correctly. When there was only one field in the collection, I didn't face any problems, and the data appeared correctly. "I think the issue might be due to my lack of experience, but I've searched online and haven't gained any useful insights